# SQL Server 2019 sys.sp_cdc_cleanup_change_table procedure not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019, change-data-capture

Although CDC works and all transactions are logged, we cannot clear the respective CDC table using the builtin procedure `sys.sp_cdc_cleanup_change_table` which should remove all the transaction except the last one. We also tried reducing the retention time to 2 minutes to see if that cleared all the transaction except the last one. It didn't.

We have CDC enabled on the database.

Then we have enabled it on the table `Packet_Store_Distribution` using the following command:

```
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_enable_table  
     @source_schema = N'dbo',  
     @source_name   = N'Packet_Store_Distribution',
     @role_name     = NULL,
     @supports_net_changes = 0
```

This works perfectly and all transactions are logged in the `cdc.dbo_Packet_Store_Distribution_CT` table as it should.

But when we try to clear this table using the query below, all the transactions still remain.

```
DECLARE @lowWaterMark binary(10);

SELECT @lowWaterMark = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn();

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_cleanup_change_table 
  @capture_instance = 'dbo_Packet_Store_Distribution_CT', 
  @low_water_mark = @lowWaterMark;
```

We also tried the following query.

```
DECLARE @maxLSN binary(10);

SELECT @maxLSN = MAX(start_lsn) FROM cdc.lsn_time_mapping;

EXEC sys.sp_cdc_cleanup_change_table 
  @capture_instance = 'dbo_Packet_Store_Distribution_CT', 
  @low_water_mark = @maxLSN;
```

Neither worked and all the transactions still remained where only the last transaction should have.

We also tried to change the retention time to 2 minutes to see if that clears all the transaction except the last one with 2 minutes interval. Still this did not work. The query is given below.

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_change_job   
    @job_type = N'cleanup',  
    @retention = 2;
```

What can cause this?